# R Shiny fit the content to the page height when a collapsed box open

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have set of collapsed boxes in a flip box in Shiny Dashboardplus. When I expand the box I want the page and the flipbox to fit the content. What is the best way to do that? Two things need to be done

1. Fit the flip box height to match the collapsed box content
2. Fit the page height to match the collapsed box content.

[image]

Below is a working sample of the issue.

```
ui.R

library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
dbHeader <- dashboardHeader()
dashboardPage(title = "Sample",skin = "blue",
              dbHeader,
              dashboardSidebar(
                sidebarMenu(id='tabs',
                  menuItem("Introduction", icon = icon("list-ul"), tabName="intro" )
              )),
              dashboardBody(
              tabItems(
                tabItem(tabName = "intro",
                        flipBox(
                          id = 1,
                          main_img ="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2779/2779923.svg",
                          header_img = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2663/2663820.svg",
                          front_title = "Sample",
                          back_title = "Sample",
                          fluidRow(
                          column(width=10,offset=1,align='left',
                          box(width=12,
                          "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent massa felis, posuere a mauris in, imperdiet auctor ipsum. In eros risus, elementum sed accumsan nec, tincidunt cursus nisi. Donec fringilla, lorem in consectetur commodo, risus urna molestie risus, vitae viverra tellus arcu ac ligula. Pellentesque condimentum ut lectus quis pulvinar. Donec ornare turpis velit, vitae hendrerit sem rutrum sed. Proin pharetra fringilla semper. Nulla vehicula gravida sem, ut posuere tellus sollicitudin sed. Curabitur risus sapien, scelerisque vel semper ut, congue ac odio. Sed bibendum quis lacus nec condimentum. Etiam quis facilisis urna. Nunc dignissim nisl sem, eu luctus turpis gravida non. Sed consectetur turpis augue, vel iaculis nibh dictum placerat. ")
                          )
                          )
                          ,
                          back_content = tagList(
                            column(
                              width = 12,
                              align = "left",
                              widgetUserBox(
                                title = "Sample",
                                subtitle = "Sample",
                                width = 3,
                                type = 2,
                                src = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2783/2783322.svg",
                                color = "blue",
                                  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent massa felis, 
                                  posuere a mauris in, imperdiet auctor ipsum. In eros risus, elementum sed 
                                  accumsan nec, tincidunt cursus nisi. Donec fringilla, lorem in consectetur commodo, 
                                  risus urna molestie risus, vitae viverra tellus arcu ac ligula.Pellentesque condimentum 
                                  ut lectus quis pulvinar. Donec ornare turpis velit, vitae hendrerit sem rutrum sed. 
                                  Proin pharetra fringilla semper. Nulla vehicula gravida sem, ut posuere tellus sollicitudin sed. 
                                  Curabitur risus sapien, scelerisque vel semper ut, congue ac odio. Sed bibendum quis lacus nec condimentum. 
                                  Etiam quis facilisis urna. Nunc dignissim nisl sem, eu luctus turpis gravida non. Sed consectetur turpis augue, 
                                  vel iaculis nibh dictum placerat. 

                              )

                            )
                          )
                        )
                )
        )    
       ))
```

server.r

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

function(input, output, session){

}
```

Comment: Could you give reproducible example?

Comment: Please check the updated post. Thank you!

Comment: I checked code with adding `"` after last `placerat.` and it doesn't seem like your image, Could you check once more? Thanks